# Calling activity Method from inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to pass a value to a fragment from its container activity.

I was trying do do it this way:

I have this method in the Activity.

```
public int showMode(){return Mode;}
```

And this method in the Fragment:

```
public int getModeFromActivity(){
    int i;
    i = getActivity().showMode;
        return i;
```

but it gives me the error in the fragment method: *showMode cannot be resolved or is not a field*

Can anyone help me fix this? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is wrong.

Here are two ways to get this job done in Android.

1.) Define an `integer mode` inside your Fragment. Change the Fragment's contructor to

```
FragmentName(int mode){
    this.mode = mode;
}
```

So you can read the mode variable in your Activity and can pass it to the Fragment at it's creation.

2.) Another way would be an Interface so your Fragment knows that its Parent Activity implements your Method! So you have to change the Fragment to something like this

```
InterfaceName mInterface;
FragmentName(MyInterfaceName interface){
    mInterface = interface;
}

public int getModeFromActivity(){
int i;
i = mInterface.showMode();
    return i;
}
```

Comment: I'm invoking the fragment in a tab host like this
TabsFragmentActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab6").setIndicator("Shop"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab6", TabFragment6.class, args)));
-- how would i invoke the constructor here?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having some difficulties. Where should i put this code? ***InterfaceName mInterface;
FragmentName(MyInterfaceName interface){
    mInterface = interface;
}***

Comment: And don't I need to declare the interface somewhere else? Like in a separate java file? Thanks and sorry for the hassle

Comment: this is a simple java callback. They explain this better here...http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html